# Fetch language declaration into JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript

So I've got a an HTML5 website setup and I've been programming a for of language toggle

The site always starts like this...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 7]><html lang="fr" class="no-js ie7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html lang="fr" class="no-js ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html lang="fr" class="no-js">
```

I'm building a language detection script and I'm trying to cache

```
<html lang="fr" class="no-js">
```

Or more specifically the "fr" and "en" into a variable upon the activation of my script...

How would I go about fetching the language declaration into a variable?

Comment: Edited your title.  JScript was the MS implementation of JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var lang = document.documentElement.getAttribute("lang");
```

or just

```
var lang = document.documentElement.lang;
```